# How to set transaction isolation level as read uncommitted as default for users

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to set the transaction isolation level to read uncommitted for users by default in MS SQL Server Management Studio 2012?

I was thinking it could either be done through editing a config file or changing a reg key but i haven't been able to locate anything that would change this yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can't change the default lock level.

For workloads with a lot of reads and fewer writes, you can avoid blocking queries with [multiversion concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control).  That's the default for Postgres and Oracle.  In SQL Server, MVCC is called ["read committed snapshot"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx), and you can enable it with:

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDb SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure it it was possible or not but thought it best to check!

Answer (score 2):

You can’t. The default isolation level for all SQL Server databases is Read Committed, and your only option is to set the isolation level within a session, if you want to use a level other than the default.

You could also set *SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL* within stored procedure body.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this.  As I'm sure you are aware; you should be careful when using the READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173763.aspx):

> When this option is set, it is possible to read uncommitted
>   modifications, which are called dirty reads. Values in the data can be
>   changed and rows can appear or disappear in the data set before the
>   end of the transaction. This option has the same effect as setting
>   NOLOCK on all tables in all SELECT statements in a transaction.

This means non of your results are guaranteed to contain accurate data.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in SQL Server Management Studio by setting execution options. (Tools>Options>Query Execution>SQL Server>Advanced>SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL>)

NB: This only does it for queries executed from this instance of SSMS.

[image]